# Mysql master slave replication - choose ip/interface (slave with multiple IPs)

Tags: mysql, interface, ip, database-mirroring

I had mysql master/slave replication running successfully. Then, I added multiple IPs to slave machine.

Now I get connection error on the slave. My guess is this is because slave is trying to connect with an IP and on master, I have created the user for other IP of slave.

Can I (if yes, then how) configure slave to connect to master using a particular fixed IP from all the interfaces available? I don't want to create different replication user at the master for different IPs of the slave.

Info: Servers running ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks

Comment: You can add a route to use a specific IP address to access IP address of master. Check out `route` command.

Comment: @ikikenis Is `route` a `mysql` command? I couldn't find any information on it by searching. Can you please elaborate a bit? Thanks.

Comment: Nope, it is an OS command. Look up "route windows" or "route linux" depending on operating system of your slave server. For example on a linux server, if you want to use eth0 interface to connect master server your command should be like 
`route add -host <serveripaddress> gw <gwipaddress> dev eth0`